# href to index.jsp page not working

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I have built a simple java-web application.

The website has three pages ("index.jsp", "info.jsp" and "contact.jsp").

When you are on the index page you can go to the nav-bar and click on "info" or on contact and then you go to the respective page.

Here's, e.g., the link leading to the contact page:

```
<a href="Contact.jsp">Contact</a>
```

The crazy thing is this:

When you click on the link to the index-page, it doesn't work - so you don't come back to the main-page.

Here's the code for the link:

```
<a href="index.jsp" class="navbar-brand">  Welcome </a>
```

What is supposed to be wrong with this code???

Comment: Add a / before index

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: I think I'm going crazy here

Comment: Can't you just do `<a href="/" class="navbar-brand">  Welcome </a>`

Comment: ok, I got it ... stupidest mistake ... I was in the wrong page ... hadn't updated the href references in the Contact page and Info page but only in the index page

Comment: thank you for your help!